# trouble creating a negative log likelihood for a linear model in R

Tags: r, regression, linear, likelihood

I am new to stats and R and I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate a function that gives me the NLL of a linear regression.

Answer (score 2):

**Preliminary Note:** In your plot you place the `dose` on the horizontal axis and `survival` on the vertical axis, yet your stated model uses `survival` as the predictor and `dose` as the response (with the result that the line on the plot is not the line-of-best-fit).  I am going to assume this is a mistake, and use `survival` as the response.

---

For a linear regression model (with normally distributed errors), the *negative log-likelihood* (NLL) is:

$$NLL(\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma) = -\ell_{\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}}(\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma) 
= \frac{n}{2} \cdot \ln(2 \pi) + n \cdot \ln(\sigma) + \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} || \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x} \boldsymbol{\beta} ||^2.$$

When you fit a linear model using th `lm` function in `R` this uses ordinary least-squares (OLS) estimation, which minimises the log-likelihood function (or equivalently, maximises the negative log-likelihood function).  Thus, at the estimated parameters values in the fitted model you have:

$$\max_{\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma} NLL(\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma) = -\ell_{\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}},\hat{\sigma}) 
= \frac{n}{2} \cdot \ln(2 \pi) + n \cdot \ln(\hat{\sigma}) + \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \cdot \text{SSE}.$$

We can calculate this maximised value of the NLL using the output from the linear model using the following `R` code:

```
#Define the data-frame and fit the linear model
DATA   <- data.frame(dose = dose, survival = survival);
MODEL  <- lm(survival ~ dose, data = DATA);

#Calculate the maximised NLL
n      <- nrow(DATA);
SSE    <- sum(MODEL$residuals^2);
sigma  <- summary(MODEL)$sigma;
MAXNLL <- (n/2)*log(2*pi) + n*log(sigma) + (1/2)*(1/sigma^2)*SSE;

MAXNLL
[1] 25.68076
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now, thank you Ben for your help!